# How to get a read only permission token on dbx for the client side?

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

Generating a Dropbox token will give write access to the project folder, which is why i need a read only token to use on the client side

I haven't been able to do anything because I haven't found any option on the developer dashboard to see the individual tokens and their permissions

```
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
var Dropbox = require('dropbox').Dropbox;
const dbx= new Dropbox({
    accessToken: 'yourAccessTokenHere',
    fetch:fetch,
    });
```

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer a read-only permission. We'll consider it a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox has released "scopes" functionality on the Dropbox API, which you can use to configure an app or access token to only a limited set of functionality, such as the ability to read but not write files.

You can find more information about the release in our blog post here:

https://dropbox.tech/developers/now-available--scoped-apps-and-enhanced-permissions

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks awesome.